# What workflow should I use to deploy a NodeJS app to a fixed server?

Tags: node.js, deployment, pm2

I work at a tiny company where deployment is mainly done by pulling `master` to a production server and running several scripts. We use PM2 which has some simple deployment features, but I'm not sure how to arrange the moving parts together to make everyone happy.

What I want to accomplish is having one fire-and-forget command to run on my dev machine that will result in everything being where it's supposed to be. What my boss wants to accomplish is to at no point have to do any lengthy step on the server to minimize downtime - so no building and no NPM install. To this end he wants builds and `node_modules` in Git and I think that's an abomination before the gods, so I'm trying to figure out how to avoid those.

Things that are a no-go for now: building and deploying Docker images, CI/CD. We don't have the infrastructure set up for those, and I'm more interested in using tools we already have and getting rid of human intervention in those. (Their popularity unfortunately also makes it hard to research best practices for more legacy environments.)

I'm not very familiar with PM2 and most of my experience is in environments where deployment was somebody else's job, so what I'm looking for is an outline of what gets done to what where provided by somebody that actually knows what they're talking about.

My current rough idea is:

1. Switch the project to Yarn 2 and use it's zero-install capability to have dependencies in Git but sane.
2. In a Docker container on the dev machine, do a clean checkout, install, and build. (This is to get rid of "works on my machine" issues and avoid inadvertently checking in macOS binaries.)
3. Push this to a release branch - these are the only ones where build outputs and such are allowed.
4. Then use PM2 to pull this specific branch and reload on the target machine.

Is this something that looks workable? Am I missing something? Is it possible to somehow avoid the release branches?

Comment: if you can not use CI/CD, why don't you write a bash script, and when you want to update project, just run your own bash

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I'm not sure how "a bash script" gives me the workflow specifics I'm after. I am aware of the various primitives of automating things at my disposal, what I'm struggling with is which one to use where and why.